# Android Studio unusable, UI and layout all display incorrectly

Tags: android-studio

I cannot upload images, here is the link on Google Drive

[image]

Does anyone come across such issue before? 
I have tried to install and uninstall over 3 times and changed jdk1.8 to 1.7 it still did not work.